# An urn containing $r$ red balls and $b$ blue balls.

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Suppose an urn contains $r$ red balls and $b$ blue balls. Suppose $n$ balls are drawn sequentially without replacement. Find the probability that $k$ of the $n$ balls are blue and that the first one is blue.

### My try:

Let $A$ be event first ball is blue and $B$ be event $k$ of $n$ balls are blue. I want to find $P(A \cap B)$. In total we have ${r+b \choose n }$ outcomes in sample space. for the number of ways $A \cap B$ occurs we have first one is blue, and so we have $b-1$ blue balls from there we pick $k$ of them so ${b - 1 \choose k}$ and for red balls we have ${r \choose n - k}$. Therefore

$$ P(A \cap B) = \frac{ b {b - 1 \choose k} {r \choose n - k} }{{r+b \choose n } }. $$

Is this correct?

Comment: If the first ball is blue, how many more blue balls must be selected from the remaining $b - 1$ blue balls in order to obtain a total of $k$ blue balls?

Comment: If $r=0,\ b=3,\ n=k=1,$ then $P(A\cap B)=1$ but your formula evaluates to $2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of alternative formulas have been given;
as noted in a comment, the formula
$$ P(A \cap B) \stackrel?= \frac{ b {b - 1 \choose k} {r \choose n - k} }{{r+b \choose n } }$$
gives wrong answers for some values of the input.

One obvious flaw in the formula is that the factor $\binom{b-1}{k}$
seems to assume that after choosing the first ball, which is blue,
you still have to choose $k$ balls from among the remaining $b-1$
blue balls, when in fact you really only want $k-1$ of those balls.
So we can try tweaking the formula as follows:
$$ P(A \cap B) \stackrel?= \frac{ b {b - 1 \choose k-1} {r \choose n - k} }{{r+b \choose n } }.$$

Now for the case $r=0, b=3, n=k=1,$ the formula gives the correct answer,
$1,$ where the earlier formula gives $2.$

But let's try $r=0, b=3, n=k=2.$ Now the revised formula evaluates to $2,$
which is clearly wrong.

So what's the flaw in the second formula? The flaw comes from your original approach to the problem. For the first ball you assumed it mattered *which* of the blue balls came first (which is how you got $b$ possibilities for that event), but for the rest of the balls you assumed it did not matter which balls came in which order (so you just choose some number from $b-1$ and some number from $r$). Meanwhile, in the denominator you assume that it does not matter in what order *any* of the balls occur, including the first one.

If you take the order of the balls into account in all cases,
then in the denominator you have $b$ ways to choose the first ball,
$\binom{b-1}{k-1}(k-1)!$ ways to choose the other $k-1$ blue balls,
$\binom{r}{n-k}(n-k)!$ ways to choose the red balls,
and $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to interleave the last $n-1$ red and blue balls.
In the denominator you have $\binom{r+b}{n}n!$ ways to choose the $n$ balls.
The result is

$$ P(A \cap B)
 = \frac{ b {b - 1 \choose k-1} (k-1)!
           {r \choose n - k}(n-k)! \binom{n-1}{k-1}}
        {{r+b \choose n }n! }
 = \frac{ b {b - 1 \choose k-1} {r \choose n - k}}
        {{r+b \choose n }n },$$
which agrees with the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(A\cap B)=P(B)P(A|B)$$
$$P(B)=\frac{\binom bk\binom r{n-k}}{\binom{r+b}n}$$
$$P(A|B)=\frac kn$$
**Alternatively**
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)$$
$$P(A)=\frac b{r+b}$$
$$P(B|A)=\frac{\binom{b-1}{k-1}\binom r{n-k}}{\binom{r+b-1}{n-1}}$$